# AVPlayer, looping video under very heavy load

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm running a tensorflow calculation on iOS, the calculation takes a few seconds so i thought it would be nice to add a loading animation (AVPlayer). The loading animation plays and loops just fine when the phone is **not** under heavy load from the tensorflow calculation, but as soon as i start running the calculation the observer for when the video is done simply stop firing, so i can't seek to the beginning and replay it.

Has anyone run into something similar? Is there any clever workarounds for playing media under heavy loads?

Comment: Can you try to perform the animation using dispatch async on a different thread?

Comment: Thanks, different thread made it work perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked! I added this as an answer. If you find it helpful please upvote, if you find it the right answer kindly mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the task using dispatch async on a different thread.

Hope this helps!